# Laravel function in controller if no route is hit

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controllers

I've been stuck with a problem in Laravel 5.

Question: Is is possible to have a default function in a Laravel controller if no other functions are activated?

Explanation:

In routes I have this:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    '/projects' => 'ProjectController'
]);
```

By doing this I can call functions in my ProjectController like getIndex or postCreate. I'd like to have the following
/projects/create, /projects/edit/{id} etc. AND /projects/{slug} <- name of project. Before, when I set all my routes individually I could just place the /projects/{slug} at the bottom and it would check for that at last.

I thought of a solution: go trough all the functions, if none of them are executed do the default function (for /projects/{slug})

How would I do this? If more code is needed, please ask! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `missingMethod`:

```
public function missingMethod($parameters = array())
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Read more in the [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#handling-missing-methods).

Comment: Maybe give him the Laravel 5 documentation instead since he's using laravel 5.0

Comment: @Loko Actually that's section is missing from the Laravel 5 docs, even thought the method is still available in the framework source code.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan! It works! Strange enough this isn't documented in the Laravel 5.0 documentation.. (oops you were ahead of me!) Will accept this answer!

Comment: @Bogdan Aha that's weird. Well then I have nothing to say